# Search algorithm but for functions

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of input (let's say they are just integers), and a list of functions (and these functions takes an integer, and returns either True or False).

I have to take this list of input, and see if any function in the list would return True for any value in the list.

Is there any way to do this faster than O(n^2)

Right now what I have is

```
for v in values:
    for f in functions:
        if f(v):
            # do something to v
            break
```

Any faster methods?

Comment: the functions are pure, i hope?  do you know anything else about them?

Comment: "return True for any value in the list" ... Does this mean the function return true for every value ... or just any one value?

Comment: This can be somewhat faster as `any(f(v) for v in values for f in functions)`, but not in less than O(n_functions * n_values) time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without any further information on the functions, the results of the `len(functions) * len(values)` possible function calls must be considered independent from each other, so there is no faster way than checking them all.

You can write this a little more concisely, though:

```
any(f(v) for v in values for f in functions)
```

The builtin function `any()` also short-circuits, just like your original code.

**Edit**: It turns out that the desired equivalent would have been

```
all(any(f(v) for f in functions) for v in values)
```

See the comments for a discussion.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no faster way. O(m*n) is the limit. If you had more information about the functions, you might be able to beat that, but in the general case, no.

Answer (score 2):

If you know more about the functions or the values, you can do what a regular search engine does- apply some sort of indexing over the values list that only requires a single pass.

EDIT:

Here's an approach with `any()` that works for this use case.

```
for v in values:
    if any(f(v) for f in functions):
        #do something to v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do better than `O(nm)` by only querying them and without some simplifying assumptions on the functions at hand.

That's because the proof that there isn't any such functions requires you to prove that, for any integer and any function, the result of the query is `False`.

To prove it, you cannot do less than perform all the queries, because your [state space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_search) is `O(2^nm)` and a query just halves the state space, so you need `O(log_2(2^nm)) = O(nm)` queries to reduce your state space to the solution "every function returns false for every integer".

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually O(n), but it saves you from iterating over the functions everytime:

```
#combine all funcs into one with `or`
newFunc = reduce(lambda f,g: (lambda x: f(x) or g(x)), funcs)

#cleaner than for, i think
satisfied = any(map(newFunc, values))
```

Discussing whether nested lambdas are pythonic is a whole different story, but I tend to think in functional terms when dealing with lists of functions.

Comment: Interesting idea. Note the in Python (2.7) `any()` is a global built-in, not a class method of list.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No, unfortunately (damn strictness...) if I had more time, I'd think of some structure that delays the `or`. But then you probably have much more overhead again - maybe almost the same as with a list. It's a vicious cycle. If you can think of an elegant solution, I'd be really interested in that.